# undefined method `sub' for nil:NilClass

Tags: amazon-s3, paperclip, aws-sdk

I'm getting the following error while using paperclip with s3.

**Undefined method `sub' for nil:NilClass**

```
def s3_object style_name = default_style
  s3_bucket.objects[path(style_name).sub(%r{\A/},'')]
end
```

Here's my has_attached_file_code & s3_credentials function:

```
has_attached_file :avatar, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }, 
                         default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png", 
                         default_style: :medium,
                         storage: :s3,
                         s3_credentials: Proc.new{|a| a.instance.s3_credentials }
validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/


def s3_credentials
{
  :s3_region => 'us-east-1',
  :bucket => "qlinkus-profile-photos", 
  :access_key_id => Rails.application.secrets.aws_access_key, 
  :secret_access_key => Rails.application.secrets.aws_secret_key
}
```

end

I have the following gems added to my gemfile:

```
gem "paperclip", git: "git://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git"
gem 'aws-sdk', ">=2.0.0"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay there are a couple of things.

Firstly, the file wasn't even getting uploaded in my server since i hadn't set the permissions for that specific folder. So Rails was getting a blank path for all the pictures, which probably caused this error, since path(style_name) was returning nil.

Even after fixing this the file wasn't getting uploaded. It got fixed after i added the following option to has_attached_file:

```
s3_permissions: 'public-read'
```

I thought that by default, the permission was set to public-read, turns out i was mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

This implies that the variable "style_name" is nil.  Perhaps it was not passed in the default value "default_style" was used which seems to be a symbol .  What is the return value from path?  I would inspect the "stye_name" variable and see what it's value is.

Answer (score 0):

I just used latest paperclip with aws-sdk v2. Following code works for me :

```
has_attached_file :doc, 
    default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png",
    storage: :s3,
    s3_credentials: Proc.new{|a| a.instance.s3_credentials },
    s3_permissions: :private,
    s3_region: ENV["AWS_REGION"]

  validates_attachment_content_type :doc, :content_type => ['image/png','image/jpg']

  def s3_credentials
    {:bucket => ENV['AWS_S3_BUCKET'], :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_KEY_ID'], :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_KEY_SECRET']}
  end
```

The only different is s3_region. Paperclip has separate configuration key for it. It is not mentioned here : http://www.rubydoc.info/github/thoughtbot/paperclip/Paperclip/Storage/S3

But when I looked at github repo I found it : 
https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip/storage/s3.rb#L219

Hope that helps!!